# Norm of a linear mapping, please check if what I have done is right

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

please check if what I have done is right.

$C[0,1]=$ continuous functions in $[0,1]$ 
considering $\|g\|=\max_t|g(t)|$
$$X=\langle t^2,1 \rangle $$
the subspace of $C[0,1]$ generated by $t^2$ and $1$

so $\forall f\in X$ exists $a$,$b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that $$f(t)=at^2+b$$
$T:X\to\mathbb{R}$

$Tf=a+b$

1.$|Tf|=|a+b|\leq \|f\|=\max\{|a+b|,|b|\}$
so this shows $\|T\|\leq 1$

2.if we take $f=t$ then $f\in X$ and $\|f\|=1$ and $|Tf|=|a=1|=1$, so this shows $\|T\|\geq 1$

1. 1 and 2 show $\|T\| =1$

let me know if this is correctly done, because I think this exercise is so easy and may be it is a trap, because other exercises are more difficult.

Comment: Two quick points about LaTeX formatting. You can use \langle and \rangle to give pointy brackets: $\langle a,b\rangle$, which I'm sure you agree looks better than $<a,b>$ (which uses inequality signs). Secondly you can use \| and \| to give the double line brackets, e.g. $\|v\|$ instead of $||v||$.

Comment: I believe it looks good! I think you meant to write $f(t) = t^2$ instead of $f(t) =t$, but otherwise, nice. You could have also taken $f(t)=1$ as an example for $|Tf| = 1 =\|f\|$.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that $Tf=|a+b|$ ? I ask this because it's not a linear map. We can suppose that : $Tf=a+b$ Is not  this ?

If  $T$ is defined like that, then:

$f(t)=t$ is not in $X$. Take $f(t)=t^2$  or $f(t)=1$ as you prefer.

Comment: I think you're right on this point -- I think Maths meant to write $Tf = a+b$ (equivalently $Tf = f(1)$).

Comment: yes ， i wrote it fast. All your points are correct. Thank-you.  I am new at math.stack  but in this short profile of time that I am here I have felt this is a great community !  Sorry for my English  I am not a English speaker